# How to clear log for Log4j 2.3 daily rolling file appender

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I am currently using log4j2 to write logs for my web application. I have configured a rolling file appender to roll over at midnight each night.

My log4j2.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile
            name="ApplicationLog"
            fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/application.log"
            filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/application %d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
              <PatternLayout>
                  <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} %l: %msg%n</Pattern>
              </PatternLayout>
              <Policies>
                  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
              </Policies>
              <DefaultRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="my.package" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ApplicationLog"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="my.test.package" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Currently, this writes to a log called application.log, then at midnight the current application.log file is copied to application yyyy-MM-dd.log (the date in the file name is replaced properly), and logging continues on the next day in application.log.

What I would like to happen is for application.log to be cleared before starting the new day. At the moment, this isn't happening, and as a result my log sizes are ever-increasing. My day 1 log contains all logging from day 1, but my day 2 log contains logging from day 1 and day 2, and so on.

How can I reset the application.log file once the rollover occurs? According to the [Log4j 2.x documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy), a new application.log file should be created, rather than the current file being continued, but this is not the behaviour I'm experiencing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

**EDIT**: Here is the configuration trace requested by rajuGT below. I can't see anything going wrong here...

```
2015-09-23 08:06:29,931 DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml]
2015-09-23 08:06:29,931 DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 69 plugins
2015-09-23 08:06:29,932 DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2015-09-23 08:06:29,934 DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 10 plugins
2015-09-23 08:06:29,939 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:29,944 DEBUG Found builder factory method [newBuilder]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.newBuilder().
2015-09-23 08:06:29,962 DEBUG TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,963 DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 21 plugins
2015-09-23 08:06:29,979 DEBUG Calling build() on class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder for element PatternLayout with params(name="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} - %msg%n", Configuration(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml), null, name="null", name="null", name="null", name="null", name="null")
2015-09-23 08:06:29,980 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 33 plugins
2015-09-23 08:06:29,981 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=layout] OK from builder factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,981 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:29,984 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,985 DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 33 plugins
2015-09-23 08:06:29,987 DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2015-09-23 08:06:29,987 DEBUG Found builder factory method [newBuilder]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.newBuilder().
2015-09-23 08:06:29,994 DEBUG No PluginVisitorStrategy found on annotation [interface org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints.Required]. Ignoring.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,994 DEBUG Encountered type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout] which can only be checked for null.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,998 DEBUG No PluginVisitorStrategy found on annotation [interface org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints.Required]. Ignoring.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,998 DEBUG Encountered type [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Target] which can only be checked for null.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,999 DEBUG No PluginVisitorStrategy found on annotation [interface org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.validation.constraints.Required]. Ignoring.
2015-09-23 08:06:29,999 DEBUG Calling build() on class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder for element Console with params(PatternLayout(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} - %msg%n), null, name="SYSTEM_OUT", name="Console", name="null", name="null")
2015-09-23 08:06:30,000 DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2015-09-23 08:06:30,001 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=appender] OK from builder factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,001 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,002 DEBUG Found builder factory method [newBuilder]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.newBuilder().
2015-09-23 08:06:30,003 DEBUG Calling build() on class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder for element PatternLayout with params(name="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} %l: %msg%n", Configuration(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml), null, name="null", name="null", name="null", name="null", name="null")
2015-09-23 08:06:30,004 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=layout] OK from builder factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,004 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,009 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,009 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,010 DEBUG Found factory method [createPolicy]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(java.lang.String,java.lang.String).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,016 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy for element TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with params(name="1", name="true")
2015-09-23 08:06:30,018 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,018 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,019 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,019 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,019 DEBUG Found factory method [createPolicy]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TriggeringPolicy[]).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,020 DEBUG Calling createPolicy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy for element Policies with params(={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy})
2015-09-23 08:06:30,020 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=Policies] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,021 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,023 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,023 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,024 DEBUG Found factory method [createStrategy]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,024 DEBUG Calling createStrategy on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy for element DefaultRolloverStrategy with params(name="null", name="null", name="null", name="null", Configuration(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml))
2015-09-23 08:06:30,025 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,025 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,026 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,026 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,026 DEBUG Found factory method [createAppender]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TriggeringPolicy,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RolloverStrategy,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,029 DEBUG Calling createAppender on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile with params(name="C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/application.log", name="C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/application %d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log", name="null", name="ApplicationLog", name="null", name="null", name="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy{TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy}), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7)), PatternLayout(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} %l: %msg%n), null, name="null", name="null", name="null", Configuration(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml))
2015-09-23 08:06:30,041 DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/application.log
2015-09-23 08:06:30,044 DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
2015-09-23 08:06:30,049 TRACE PatternProcessor.getNextTime returning 2015/09/24-00:00:00.000, nextFileTime=2015/09/23-00:00:00.000, prevFileTime=1970/01/01-10:00:00.000, current=2015/09/23-08:06:30.048, freq=DAILY
2015-09-23 08:06:30,049 TRACE PatternProcessor.getNextTime returning 2015/09/24-00:00:00.000, nextFileTime=2015/09/23-00:00:00.000, prevFileTime=2015/09/23-00:00:00.000, current=2015/09/23-08:06:30.049, freq=DAILY
2015-09-23 08:06:30,050 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=appender] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,050 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,051 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,051 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,051 DEBUG Found factory method [createAppenders]: public static java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin.createAppenders(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender[]).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,052 DEBUG Calling createAppenders on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin for element Appenders with params(={Console, ApplicationLog})
2015-09-23 08:06:30,052 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=appenders] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,052 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,053 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,053 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,053 DEBUG Found factory method [createAppenderRef]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,054 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(name="ApplicationLog", name="null", null)
2015-09-23 08:06:30,054 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=AppenderRef] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,055 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,055 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,056 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,056 DEBUG Found factory method [createLogger]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.createLogger(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,057 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element Logger with params(name="false", name="INFO", name="my.package", name="null", ={ApplicationLog}, ={}, Configuration(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml), null)
2015-09-23 08:06:30,059 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=logger] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,059 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,059 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,060 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,060 DEBUG Found factory method [createAppenderRef]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,061 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(name="Console", name="null", null)
2015-09-23 08:06:30,061 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=AppenderRef] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,061 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,061 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,062 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,062 DEBUG Found factory method [createLogger]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.createLogger(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,064 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig for element Logger with params(name="false", name="DEBUG", name="my.test.package", name="null", ={Console}, ={}, Configuration(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml), null)
2015-09-23 08:06:30,064 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=logger] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,065 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,065 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,065 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,066 DEBUG Found factory method [createAppenderRef]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,066 DEBUG Calling createAppenderRef on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef for element AppenderRef with params(name="Console", name="null", null)
2015-09-23 08:06:30,066 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=AppenderRef] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,067 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,067 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,067 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,068 DEBUG Found factory method [createLogger]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger.createLogger(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,068 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger for element Root with params(name="null", name="ERROR", name="null", ={Console}, ={}, Configuration(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml), null)
2015-09-23 08:06:30,069 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=root] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,069 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,071 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,071 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin]. Searching for factory method...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,071 DEBUG Found factory method [createLoggers]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Loggers org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin.createLoggers(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig[]).
2015-09-23 08:06:30,072 DEBUG Calling createLoggers on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin for element Loggers with params(={my.package, my.test.package, root})
2015-09-23 08:06:30,072 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=loggers] OK from factory method.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,074 DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml] OK.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,075 TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@43db0439...
2015-09-23 08:06:30,075 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 AsyncLoggerConfigs.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,075 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 AsyncAppenders.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,075 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 1 Appenders.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,076 TRACE AbstractConfiguration stopped 0 Loggers.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,076 DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@43db0439 OK
2015-09-23 08:06:30,083 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478
2015-09-23 08:06:30,087 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478,component=StatusLogger
2015-09-23 08:06:30,089 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478,component=ContextSelector
2015-09-23 08:06:30,092 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478,component=Loggers,name=
2015-09-23 08:06:30,093 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478,component=Loggers,name=my.package
2015-09-23 08:06:30,093 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478,component=Loggers,name=my.test.package
2015-09-23 08:06:30,095 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478,component=Appenders,name=Console
2015-09-23 08:06:30,096 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=672866478,component=Appenders,name=ApplicationLog
2015-09-23 08:06:30,096 DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=672866478] at null (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@655b289) with optional ClassLoader: null
2015-09-23 08:06:30,097 DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2015-09-23 08:06:30,100 DEBUG LoggerContext[name=672866478, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@655b289] started OK.
```

Comment: You mean, not the file content. The log folder size is increasing? am I right?

Comment: The application.log file size is increasing, and every day this file gets duplicated to the daily file, which as a result is also increasing. In other words, application.log contains logs from day 1 to day infinity until I delete the file. I want application.log to contain the logs from the **current day only**, as this content is backed up at midnight when the file is duplicated

Comment: FWIW, I think log4j *moves* the current log file to the dated-name and then opens a new file. I'm struggling to understand how this could fail. :(

Comment: I read the code in the DefaultRolloverStrategy class and I agree... not sure how this is failing either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this one out by debugging through the source code as my logs were supposed to roll over.

Apparently, there is an undocumented attribute that can be placed in the RollingFile element called "append", which, when set to **false**, will write the current log file from the beginning. Unfortunately, the default value for this attribute is **true**, which causes the current log file to be appended rather than restarted.

So my final log4j2.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile
            name="ApplicationLog"
            fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/application.log"
            filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/application %d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            append="false">
              <PatternLayout>
                  <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{36} %l: %msg%n</Pattern>
              </PatternLayout>
              <Policies>
                  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
              </Policies>
              <DefaultRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="my.package" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ApplicationLog"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="my.test.package" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Hopefully this helps someone else figure out this problem in less than the 3 days that it took me.

**EDIT**: So it turns out that this attribute is documented [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) (the first parameter in the table), but it still doesn't make sense to me why appending is the default behaviour. Why would I want my file size to be forever increasing!? Anyway, not the point, just ranting!

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: The edit above = [eating humble pie like a boss!](http://imgur.com/gallery/4uNWjmM)

Comment: Please raise this issue on the log4j-user mailing list or file a Jira ticket for this to get feedback from the log4j community. You may have found a bug.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. The default behaviour makes perfect sense once I read the documentation properly. It just doesn't make sense why they chose that as the default. I hope this sentence makes sense! :)

Comment: One thing to note... if you implement the `<OnStartupTriggerPolicy...>`, the `append=false` will overwrite the existing log file with a blank file, causing you to lose the data, especially when you bounce the server multiple times in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-610) you are facing.

Check the **folder permissions** for the log folder and give write permission to it.

```
chmod 666 logs
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this definitely isn't the problem. All users have Full Control permissions in this directory (and all subdirectories). I probably should also have mentioned above that I am using Windows 10 in case it's relevant

Comment: Okay. Change `<Configuration status="WARN">` to TRACE and see at the start of the application, whether any configuration log4j is not able to read.

Comment: I have edited my original post and added the log that came from this. I don't notice any problems though